# PERSONAL.XLSB MacroOptions on startup

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I would like to register my PERSONAL.XLSB UDFs as soon as I open a new workbook. I have a `Workbook_Open()` event call the following:

```
Sub RegisterUDF()
    Dim s As String
    s = "Enter 0 for x resolution" & vbLf _
    & "1 for y resolution"

    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="GetSystemMetrics", Description:=s, Category:=9, HelpFile:="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx"
End Sub
```

where `GetSystemMetrics` is my UDF and the code is placed in the workbook object and a module of my Personal.xlsb

Upon opening a new workbook, something appears to run becaue I get the error message:[image: Error]

How should I fix my code to register the UDF on every new workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying @Peh 's approach and reading the error messages, I find this works:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Dim t As String
t = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Windows("PERSONAL.XLSB").Visible = True
Call RegisterUDF
Windows("PERSONAL.XLSB").Visible = False
Windows(t).Visible = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused when the `RegisterUDF` is run before the workbook is fully loaded. Try to add the following in the `Workbook_Open` event *before* you call `RegisterUDF`.

```
Do Until Application.Ready = True
DoEvents: Loop
```

---

If the solution above doesn't work The following might be an alternative way:

Try the `Workbook_Activate` event which happens after `Workbook_Open`.
Otherwise, if it is necessary to cause a delay, you can use the `OnTime` method in the `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "RegisterUDF"
```

This will run the `RegisterUDF` procedure after a 2 second delay.

Comment: Nice one. Just a side question. Why 2 seconds? Whenever I have to define the wait time hard-coded in my script, I have this question. Not for this one specifically, but for example calling shell. Apart from using `Do Until` sometimes I still need to add some wait. Do you have any method or something for that?

Comment: @Masoud Just randomly 2 seconds because most times 2 seconds are enough time to finish other actions. Many actions only need a couple of milliseconds but it still can be that 2 seconds is not enough so will have to test this on your setup as this also depends on the performance of your system. We have to keep in mind that this is still just a workaround because of Excel hates us.